# Jasper Report Image Format Exception if report too long

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext

We have been using JasperReports as a report writer in our Java application for about 8 years. Mostly this has been good, but we've had one issue recently which has stumped us.

We have a report which has a company logo on the first page. This report is usually less than 2 pages long, and works fine.

However, when the report goes over onto the third page (which happens very, very rarely), we get the following exception when we are trying to export it to PDF:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1747)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.process(JRPdfExporter.java:1604)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.access$300(JRPdfExporter.java:1532)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1472)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1090)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:3117)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1098)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1053)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:917)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:537)
    .... 
    (our application)
    ....
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
    at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1742)
    ... 47 more
```

NOTE: We can view the report fine in the Jasper viewer, the error only occurs when we export it to PDF to email the report.

The current version of Jasper we are using is 6.4.1, which includes version 2.1.7-js6 of itext (the source of the exception).

Comment: Please read [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) You are using a version of iText that has been declared "end of life" many years ago and that [should no longer be used after legal issues were identified](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/435). Since TIBCO / JasperSoft is not a customer of iText Group, this is not the responsibility of iText, but the responsibility of TIBCO. For that reason, tagging this question as an iText question is wrong.

Comment: It would be hard to identify the problem without being able to reproduce it. There must be something special about the third page. Maybe the logo is repeating on even pages? Try to create a simpler report that you can share with us. You could maybe fill it with an empty data source that has a certain number of records so that it produces at least 3 pages. This way we could run it on our side and see what's wrong.